# Find the aggregate values of each column and transform that to a row

Tags: sql

```
create table test(
oldnum varchar(32),
newnum  varchar(32),
id varchar(32),
transactioncnt int);

Insert into test(oldnum,newnum,id,transactioncnt) values 
(220,220,839,22),
(220,220,4,12),
(221,221,1234,10),
(221,222,475,10),
(221,222,687,15),
(225,221,837,60);
```

output columns:
`oldnum`,`oldnumTotalTransactionCnt`,`newnum`,`newtransactionCntcontributedfromOldnum`,`newnumTotalTransactionCnt`

expected output

```
220,34,220,34,34
221,35,221,10,70
221,35,222,25,25
225,60,221,60,70
```

1. if oldnum = newnum for all the records(rows) then just get the sum(transationcnt) and group by oldnum. same values can be filled for different columns
2. If  oldnum <> newnum , sum(transactioncnt) for oldnum is oldnumTotalTransactionCnt, and see if the newnum exits somewhere else in newnum column and take the sum for the newnumTotalTransactionCnt, newtransactionCntcontributedfromOldnum will be what ever the transactioncnt coming from oldnum

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in `varchar` columns? Beyond that question, it appears that this is a homework assignment. So what have you tried so far? It won't do you any good to have us do your homework for you. If you post what you've tried, someone will come along to give some guidance.

Comment: Where does 34 come from?

Answer (score 0):

Window functions come handy for this, since they give you the ability to compute `sums`s over different partitions at once:

```
select distinct
    oldnum,
    sum(transactioncnt) over(partition by oldnum) oldnumTotalTransactionCnt,
    newnum,
    sum(transactioncnt) over(partition by oldnum, newnum) newtransactionCntcontributedfromOldnum,
    sum(transactioncnt) over(partition by newnum) newnumTotalTransactionCnt
from test
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce47f8148eccf39e4ef9e8524c947e5a)**:

```
oldnum | oldnumTotalTransactionCnt | newnum | newtransactionCntcontributedfromOldnum | newnumTotalTransactionCnt
-----: | ------------------------: | -----: | -------------------------------------: | ------------------------:
   220 |                        34 |    220 |                                     34 |                        34
   221 |                        35 |    221 |                                     10 |                        70
   225 |                        60 |    221 |                                     60 |                        70
   221 |                        35 |    222 |                                     25 |                        25
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to think of this as an aggregation query, with addition columns added using aggregation.

The basic query is:

```
select oldnum,
       newnum,
       sum(transactioncnt) as newtransactionCntcontributedfromOldnum,
from test
group by oldnum, newnum
order by 1, 3;
```

Then you want to sum up the `sum(transactioncnt)` for both `oldnum` and `newnum`.  That is where the window functions come in:

```
select oldnum,
       sum(sum(transactioncnt)) over (partition by oldnum) as oldnumTotalTransactionCnt,
       newnum,
       sum(transactioncnt) as newtransactionCntcontributedfromOldnum,
       sum(sum(transactioncnt)) over (partition by newnum) as newumTotalTransactionCnt
from test
group by oldnum, newnum
order by 1, 3;
```